# How to create a self signed certificate using SelfSSL

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I have created a self signed certificate using IIS Manager but when I try to access to the website I only find this message:

[image: Certificate doesn't match URL]

I found [this tutorial](http://www.robbagby.com/iis/self-signed-certificates-on-iis-7-the-easy-way-and-the-most-effective-way/) which describes pretty well my problem: My certificate is issued for the computers local network name instead of the website adrress. The tutorial explains how to create the certificate using SelfSSL. 
Now my problem is that when I run the SelfSSL it doesn't show any error, but neither create any certificate...

Is there any other way to create self signed certificates issued correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here: [Create a Self-Signed Certificate within IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494864/create-a-self-signed-certificate-within-iis-express), make use of Visual Studio `makecert`, it may be worth the try. Also here is a tutorial for using OpenSSL for the same purpose: http://www.dylanbeattie.net/docs/openssl_iis_ssl_howto.html.

Comment: Thank you! You make my day. I used OpenSSL to create my certificate and now everything is working fine.