# Setting up trust for SSL sites hosted in IISExpress

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ssl, iis-express

When I try to browse any SSL site in IISExpress over ports 44300 - 44399, the site shows up as untrusted.

The following links discuss how to setup IIS to serve externally and/or moving the cert from the Personal to Trusted root.
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx
[Create a Self-Signed Certificate within IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494864/create-a-self-signed-certificate-within-iis-express)

I don't really want to server externally over port 443. What I'd like is for the cert that IISExpress installs to be trusted so that any SSL sites in the port range 44300 - 44399 are considered trusted.

I've tried moving the IISExpress cert from the Personal to the Trusted root store but this does not seem to work.

Is this at all possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I did it, which is probably the simplest way possible:

1. Run your website to start IISExpress.
2. [Run IE as an Administrator](https://superuser.com/a/713821/129855) and browse to your SSL-enabled site.
3. Install the certificate into the *Trusted Root Certification Authorities*:

[image]

That's it.

**I only recommend doing this on a development box.** If the IISExpress cert isn't generated randomly for your machine (does it? I don't know), there are serious security implications for putting the cert in the trusted store. If you're concerned, better to follow the more complicated set up of creating your own CAcert locally.