# Does enabling SSL require more than just turning it on?

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

I run an nginx-powered application and I recently turned my attention to using it over https. This is the module in nginx that does this: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule

However, I'm somewhat unclear about what is actually required to run a site over https.

What else is there to do to serve my site over ssl? What is the role of the certificate, and is it a requirement that I purchase it from somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a certificate to prove to your user that the server they're connected to is indeed the one intended (and not a MITM attacker).

If your server is to be used by a limited number of users to whom you could give a certificate explicitly, you could use a self-signed certificate or create your own certification authority (CA).

Otherwise, if you want your certificate to be recognised by most browsers, you'll need to get one from a commercial CA.

You should find more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4024848/372643). You may also be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8186312/372643).